# Finding the name of the object a function returns to

Tags: r, function

My question is the following. Given the following function:

```
spam <- function() {
  cat("eggs\n")
}

bla <- spam()
```

I want to find the name of the object the function is returning its content to. In the example `bla <- spam()` this would be `bla`. Using `match.call` I can find the call that was performed:

```
match.call()
function() {
      cat("eggs\n")
    }
```

this, however, does not include the name of the object the function returns to. I've looked around on the R-help list, google and SO, but could not find anything useful. Any suggestions how to proceed?

**Background**
From the replies I gather that what I want is a bit on the esotheric side. I'd explain where I'm coming from, this might shed some light on my motives. The context I'm working in has to do with testing, and more specifically, testing whether or not a certain object changes in time (e.g. model output).

Normally a user will write a bunch of code that generates an object, save it and compare the saved object to newly generated objects as time goes on. The user can do this using the following function:

```
spam <- testReferenceChange(expression)
```

Normally this function will read the reference and generate a new object, which the user can compare to each other. For regenerating the reference file, I wanted to use the exact same code. I do this by changing a global option (see `options` and `getOption`), `recalculate`. We running this function in the recalculation mode, new references are stored. And now for the reason to my question. In saving the reference to file (using `save()`) I wanted to use the name of the object the user returns to, combined with a date, to create a unique name.

Comment: The `spam` has no knowledge of where it will be assigned and cannot even "see" the (future) name that will be given to its result. The assignment of a names is being done by `<-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...I find it hard to imagine why you would want this. Also, your `spam` function returns `NULL` so it seems even more pointless...

Nevertheless, the simplest/cleanest way to do this is to pass in the name to the `spam` function!

```
spam <- function(name) {
   cat(name, "<- eggs\n")
   42 # return a value
}


bla <- spam("bla")
```

Advancing to the next level, you could have `spam` do the assignment. You can also play with `substitute` to allow specifying the name without quotes:

```
spam <- function(name) {
   name <- as.character(substitute(name))
   cat(name, "<- eggs\n")
   value <- 42
   assign(name, value, parent.frame())
}

spam(bla)
bla # 42
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have a good reason for going this way, and the function returns NULL because a return value is not important for my question.

Comment: I'm leaning towards your more simple solution, thanks again. I was just wondering if I could solve it this way :).

Comment: it is a bit of a long story. Tomorrow at work I'll give it a go. Currently on my smartphone :)

Comment: I added some background to my question above

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and thought of that solution... It's probably not perfect but so far I had good results with it.

```
getLastCreatedObj <- function() {
  tmpfile <- tempfile("hist", fileext = ".txt")
  savehistory(file = tmpfile)
  last_command <- tail(readLines(tmpfile), 2)[1]
  unlink(tmpfile)
  if (grepl("^[a-zA-Z_.0-9]+\\s*(<-|=)", last_command)) {
    all_names <- all.names(as.expression(parse(text = s)))
    varname <- all_names[grep("(<-|=)", all_names) + 1]
    return(varname)
  }
  return(NULL)
}
```

Note that you can't use it in a package; it fails check with the message `'savehistory' can only be used in Rgui and Rterm`.